# Taking a tenner from neighbour

Tags: mathematics

Let's define the first number as "ab" and the second number as "cd". In "ab"-"cd" proces, if "b" is smaller than "d", we add 10 to "b" and reduce 1 from "a".

In Turkish, we called it "taking a tenner from neighbour". How do you use that term in English?

Comment: In English, a tenner is an informal word for a £10 note. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/tenner?q=tenner

Comment: This might be better asked on Math.SE or a specialist teaching forum. You're describing the ***Decomposition method*** of subtraction, but I don't think there's a formal way of expressing **how** that is carried out. When I was at school we used to say *borrow one from here which makes ten in this column*. I rather like "take a tenner from a neighbour"!

Comment: I am completely baffled by this question, would you be so kind as to explain it using simpler language so that I might understand

Comment: Yes - decomposition. For instance, 47 - 23 = 24, no problem (we're using the usual algorithm, 7 - 3, and then 4 - 2 in the tens column): (40 + 7) - (20 + 3) But what about 54 - 28 = ? The problem is that 8 can't be subtracted from 4 using only positive numbers. So, we recognise that 54 - 28 = (40 + 14) - (20 + 8) and now we **can** handle the units (14 - 8 = 6) and then the resulting tens (40 - 20) **Instead of** regarding 54 the obvious way (50 + 4), we've decomposed the 50 into 40 + 10, transferring a ten from the tens to the units.

Comment: A great deal of the confusion in mathematics education arose when teachers talked about the _decomposition method_ without explaining to parents that it was what they had learned as _borrow and pay back_.

Comment: Agreed - though that terminology was itself inaccurate. _Internal transfer_ maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English this is called *borrowing*:

> 32 − 15
>   = (20 + 12) − (10 + 5)
>   “borrow the 1”
>   = (20 − 10) + (12 − 5)
>   = 10 + 7
>   = 17

Going the other direction, as in addition, is called *carrying*:

> 25 + 39
>   = (20 + 5) + (30 + 9)
>   = (20 + 30) + (5 + 9)
>   = (20 + 30) + 14
>   “carry the 1”
>   = (20 + 30 + 10) + 4
>   = 60 + 4
>   = 64

Both are special cases of *regrouping*.